# Admin Panel: Channels Grouping in Multiple Groups

Tags: entries, admin, channels

In the admin panel, under "Entries", the "Channels" grouping has become disorganized as I have added new Channels over time. It seems as I add new channels, they stick to a group for a while, then over time, create a whole other grouping on the side.

[image]

Can someone give me an idea of what may be happening here so I can resolve it?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange your sections however you like - hit the cog dropdown at the bottom of your screenshot to Customise Sources.

[image]

Comment: Wow, to think I always click on that menu to adjust the displayed columns in the tables. Never realized I could sort the sub navigation. Thanks a ton!